# The name 'EachVar' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

I successfully created an int variable in the button i entered that variable in.
but each time i try to insert that variable to an another object (in this case another button), i get "The name 'EachVar' does not exist in the current context"

The code:

```
     private void Set1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (PAT.Text != "" && Loading1.Value != 100 && Loading1.Value - 100 <= 0)
        {
        int EachVar = Convert.ToInt32(PAT.Text); //The Var 'EachVar'
        label1.Text = "Value: " + Convert.ToString(EachVar);
        }
    }


    private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Loading1.Value + EachVar < 100) // The Error
        {
            Timer1.Start();
            Timer1.Interval = 1000;
        }
        else
        {
            Loading1.Value = 100;
            Timer1.Stop();
        }
    }
```

Comment: [Scopes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), [Variable & method scopes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx)

Comment: Put everything in one button ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your code is written, the variable will only be defined / exist within the `{}`-scope surrounding it - that is the method `Set1_Click()`.

You want to define it outside it, so that it can be accessed in both methods:

```
// Now it can be accessed throughout the class. 
// Note that I've called it "_eachVar" to follow the naming convention for 
// fields in a class. 
private int _eachVar = 0; 

private void Set1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (PAT.Text != "" && Loading1.Value != 100 && Loading1.Value - 100 <= 0)
    {
    _eachVar = Convert.ToInt32(PAT.Text); //The Var 'EachVar'
    label1.Text = "Value: " + Convert.ToString(EachVar);
    }
}


private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Loading1.Value + _eachVar < 100) // The Error
    {
        Timer1.Start();
        Timer1.Interval = 1000;
    }
    else
    {
        Loading1.Value = 100;
        Timer1.Stop();
    }
}
```

Also note that you could have used a property which hides the backing field..

```
private int EachVar
{
    get { return _eachVar; }
    set { _eachVar = value; }
}
```

Or an auto-implemented property (where the corresponding field is "hidden"):

```
private int EachVar {get; set;}
```